# The Slowest Microprocessor

Tags: microprocessor

I've read that Z3, first electromechanical general purpose computer operated at a frequency of about 5–10 Hz, and the ENIAC had a 100 kHz clock, though each instruction took 20 cycles.

What microprocessor has the lowest clock speed? I'm curious about fixed speed processors and the lowest minimum and maximums on devices with variable clock speeds.

By microprocessor I mean the definition given by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor): A computer processor where the data processing logic and control is included on a single integrated circuit, or a small number of integrated circuits.

Comment: You might need to be more specific on what you mean by "microprocessor."  Do you mean something on a *single* integrated circuit?

Comment: I mean a CPU composed of a small number of integrated circuits, not necessarily one. I'll edit to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Most (fully static) CMOS CPUs can go down to zero with their minimum clock speed. So, asking for the *minimum* is not really a useful question for such chips. I guess you want the *slowest maximum speed*.

Comment: Can you define better if you simply mean slowest clock frequency, or slowest clocks per instruction, or slowest to execute instructions, slowest bus cycles, slowest performance? Because clock frequency does not alone define how slow a CPU is.

Comment: I'm just referring to the clock frequency. Anything else and things get too complicated for comparison.

Comment: Then your question is not very useful (or rather, very ambigous). Even a Z80A, which is nominally clocked at 4MHz, runs on a clock as low as 250kHz according to the datasheet.

Comment: Presumably there are internal PLLs that multiply the oscillator frequency up to the actual clock frequency of the processor?

Comment: You seriously believe that a site like Wikipaedia is a reliable source for such a definition?

Comment: @Chenmunka that response seems a little bafflingly hostile don't you think? What is wrong with that definition of a microprocessor?

Comment: Let me rephrase that.  Wikipedia is not a reliable source for ANY information.  Please see the questions on Meta discussing this.

Comment: @alessandro Because that definition is a quite vague one, letting room for anything from modern integration monsters all the way down to a bunch of TTL ( a simple CPU does not need much). So it essentially only excludes designs with discrete components. Not useful at all - even less useful as a base for further research: building a house in a swamp isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Raffzahn I want to exclude a bunch of ttl as the thats pretty clearly arbitrarily clockable on the low end.

Comment: @Chenmunka would you prefer encyclopedia Britannica? A microprocessor, any of a type of miniature electronic device that contains the arithmetic, logic, and control circuitry necessary to perform the functions of a digital computer’s central processing unit.

Comment: @alessandro Then you can not use the definition from Wikipedia, as _"or a small number of integrated circuits."_ fits quite well a hand full of TTl, doesn't it? Also many CPUs can be as well clocked at arbitrary low frequencies, so do you want exclude them as well - if not, then 1 give you a 1 mHz 1802 - one clock per 20 minutes :) In addition, the EB definition does as well not solve this, but rather waters the swamp, as it does not define what _'device'_ means. :))

Comment: I mean the issue here is how micro is the microprocessor isn't it? I would consider a handful of ttls to be quite a bit more than a few. As far as static processors, I didn't know about that and by asking this question I learned something new.

Comment: @alessandro Yeah, but what has to be part of a CPU? Registers? Not really, Programm counter? There are CPU with program counter off chip. ALU? Why, an adder can be enough. And so on. It's possible to build a CPU with anything between 3 and 10 TTL (a hand full). If you dig deeper you'll learn that the term microprocessor in itself is not a clear one, but rather one of those terms everyone feels to understand, but in reality it's rather fuzzy. **Oh, and one more:** you're aware that asynchronous processors exist? They got no clock to regulate their workings at all, they just crunch along.  :))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any CPU that is [fully-static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_core) can be clocked down to 0 Hz and still function.  Such CPUs are in wide use today.  Here are some examples:

- [RCA 1802](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_1802)
  Used in a few early micros, as an embedded processor, and in space applications such as Galileo (Jupiter) and Magellan (Venus).  It also was the initial platform for [CHIP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8).
- [Intel 80386EX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386EX)
  A variant of the 386 targeting embedded applications.
- WDC W65C02S
  Fully-static version of the ubiquitous [65C02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65C02).
- WDC W65C816S
  Fully-static version of the [65C816](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65C816) (enhanced 8-/16-bit version of the 65C02).
- [Freescale 683XX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_683XX)
  Microcontroller using a fully-static 68000-based core.
- The new tinyAVR chips (0-, 1-, and 2-series, e.g. ATtiny204) seem to be fully static.  They're rated down to 0 Hz and I've personally run them as low as ~683 Hz.

Comment: Obviously, the intent of the question was different. What was the lowest **maximum** speed of a microprocessor?

Comment: @LeoB. I think a more interesting question is what non-static processor has/had the lowest minimum clock speed.

Comment: That would be a somewhat different question, about the most "slowable" processor rather than the slowest.

Comment: afaik any AVR mcu, incl. the oldest ones, was static, as well as all 8bit PICs by microchip, and all AT89 mcs-51-compatible mcus by atmel.

Comment: @LeoB. I would argue that there is no intent of the question. It's a random "gee I wonder" question that has nothing to do on any stack exchange site, except curiously retrocomputing where such questions are accepted.

Comment: Yes, this is just a trivia question. But I find you can still learn a lot from asking these kind of questions

Answer (score 18):

Going with the spirit of the question.

A quick glance at Wikipedia's [Microprocessor Chronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor_chronology) we find:

- PPS-4 from Rockwell at 200 kHz
- PPS-8 from Rockwell at 256 kHz
- TMS 1000 from TI at 400 kHz
- PPS-25 from Fairchild at 400 kHz
- IMP-4 from National at 500 kHz
- 8008 from Intel at 500 kHz
- IMP-8 & -16 from National at 715 kHz
- the 4004 and 4040 from Intel at 740 kHz

So, I would say the PPS-4 "wins", while the Intel 8008 is probably the slowest chip that may be commonly known.

Comment: The PPS-4 runs at 4× the base frequency (i.e. ~800 kHz on a 199 kHz "A" clock).  See [here](https://en.wikichip.org/w/index.php?title=File:rockwell_pps-4_data_sheet_(1974).pdf&page=15) and [here](https://en.wikichip.org/w/index.php?title=File:rockwell_pps-4_data_sheet_(1974).pdf&page=18). However, the [datasheet](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/ti/TMS1000/TMS_1000_Series_MOS_LSI_One-Chip_Microcomputers_1975.pdf) (p. 14) for the TMS1000 says that it'll run down to 100 kHz (and possibly lower; setting the internal oscillator to 40 kHz is described on p. 15).

Comment: The TMS1000 also wasn't static (it used DRAM for its registers).  See [here](https://www.righto.com/2020/11/reverse-engineering-ram-storage-in.html) for details on how it was implemented.

Answer (score 8):

Not the slowest in clock speeds (a whopping 1MHz), but probably the simplest and slowest in raw performance of its time may be the Motorola MC14500 CPU - It only has a 1-bit data bus and only 16 instructions.

Given that not all (especially industry control) applications need more than "on" and "off" as inputs and outputs, it was still a very versatile thing to have.

Answer (score -1):

Other answers are correct about other microprocessors that can run at very low speeds and still be functional. For example, I have a RocketChip for my Apple II which is a 6502 that can be controlled via software to run at the default 1MHz or accelerated 5MHz, but can also be tuned down to 50kHz.

However, I think the nature of the question is more around CPUs and their native speeds. If that is the case, if I exclude minis and mainframes and focus on desktop, I *think* the Intel 4004 might be the lowest since its native clock was 750kHz and I can't recall many others in the kHz range that go lower than that.